# ReactJS - How to send data to the PayPal Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

It's probably very simple, but how do you send information to the PayPal button component?
For example, the name of the products, the total value ?

Here is what I did, I tested my code and I get a "transaction success" :

```js
// In panierPage, where the user can click on the PayPal button
import PayPal from '../services/PayPal/paypal'

    return (
                <Grid style={{marginLeft: '2%'}}>
                    <PayPal/>
                </Grid>
        );
```

```js
// PayPal Button component with "default value " for testing
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Paypal() {

    const paypal = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        window.paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                color: 'gold',
            },
            createOrder: (data, actions) => {
                return actions.order.create({
                    intent: 'CAPTURE',
                    purchase_units: [
                        {
                            description: 'Une table',
                            amount: {
                                currency_code: 'EUR',
                                value: '10.00'
                            }
                        }]
                })
            },
            onApprove: (data, actions) => {
                console.log("Transaction Réussite")
                return actions.order.capture();
            },
            onCancel: (data, actions) => {
                
            }
        }).render(paypal.current)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={paypal}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Because right now, it's hard coded price and description.

Thanks for the time and the help !

Answer (score 1):

You replace the hard coded values with dynamically set ones. Use variables, call a function like `document.getElementById`, or your own custom function that generates an item list array, or whatever you wish to do to obtain the necessary values values; it's JavaScript.

The result just needs to evaluate at runtime to a valid v2 Orders request object. The full syntax of the object is documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I manage to get the data via a simple props. But thanks for your explanation and your time ! I will post my answer and close this question when I can (In 2 days).

Comment: Properties are the JSX equivalent of variables, so yes